# Deserializing Key-Value Pair

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, windows-phone-7

Hi I am getting a response from server which is something like this

```
{"total":110,"responses":{"13":26,"14":24,"15":40,"16":20}}
```

I am not able to deserialize it using DataContractJSONSerializer. I have tried various combination for it but no results.
I am using following class for de-serializing:

```
public class PollResponseRoot
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> Responses;

}
```

but I always get the Response value null. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: The JSON string is legitimate JSON.

Comment: what does that mean, excuse me for my naiveness i am new to .net and wp7

Comment: I'm just letting you know the problem is not in the format of the JSON string.

Comment: yeah, thanks for that, strange thing if i change the name of the Dictionary in my class from Responses to responses , i get argument exception. while De-serializing

Comment: How about

    public Dictionary<string, int> responses; Oh and mark the class as a DataContractAttribute and the properties as DataMember. You could also specify [DataMember(Name="responses")] to leave the property name properly PascalCased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are not supported by DataContractJsonSerializer, you could try your luck with [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) instead.

Also available on NuGet: http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Bendik json.net is available for windows phone 7 ?, i tried including the .net3.5 binaries and got a warning that "including this lib can have unexpected application behavior"

Comment: Json.net should be very much available on wp7, i have used on several occasions, but you need the 4.0 version or you could just add it to the project by using NuGet

Answer (score 2):

See [my explanation on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170171/parsing-complex-json/8175522#8175522) why it's not possible to decode such lists using `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) instead.